# Sustituir valores de un csv con awk

Tags: csv, awk

Estoy intentando cambiar los valores nulos de una columna por el valor de su media.
He realizado los cálculos, pero no me sustituye la información en el fichero.

Mi codigo:

```
BEGIN {
    FS= ";"
    total=0;
    count=0;
}
{
   if ($13 != "NULL")
       {
        total += $13;
        count +=1;
       }
}
END {
media += total/count;
}
BEGIN {
    FS= ";"
    count2=0;
}
{
    if ($13 == "NULL")
    {
     $13 = media;
     count2= +=1
    }
}
END {
printf("Filas sustituidas:" count2);
}
```

Al ejecutar veo correctamente que debería haber sustituido 59 filas, sin embargo el fichero no se modifica. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que lo sustituya en el fichero original?
No me importa que sea en uno nuevo, pero necesito poder almacenar el cambio realizado.

**1ª Edición:** Edito para ampliar información:

El csv viene separado por ; y mi variable a reemplazar está en la columna M -->por eso el 13

[image: fichero.csv]

Estoy ejecutando de esta manera:

```
gawk -f script.awk archivo.csv
```

La media y el total de filas que debería sustituir son correctas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2ªEdicion:** Añado la url de donde descargué el dataset.
https://datos.madrid.es/egobfiles/MANUAL/300110/AccidentesBicicletas_2021.csv

Comment: Pon la instrucción de como lo estas ejecutando ahora y si puede ser un poco del csv

Comment: Hola @masterguru   , he editado añadiendo tanto la vista del fichero csv como la ejecución del script

Comment: Me da un error en esta linea `count2= +=1`... ¿a ti tambien? `gawk: script.awk:24:              ^ syntax error`... y si quito el `=` y dejo el resto no me suma nada, simplemente me da `Filas sustituidas:0`

Comment: Vale, ya me ha sustituido una.. le he tenido que poner NULL en lugar de dejarla en blanco... a ver pues...

Comment: @masterguru la cuestión es que he puesto ese count2 para verificar que pase por ahi, pero no me realiza la sustitución. O si la hace, no la graba. ME refiero a la línea $13 =  media. ¿Debo añadir algo más para que reescriba el fichero?

Comment: Más que reescribir el fichero lo que estoy intentando es escribir uno nuevo, pero no consigo que la variable "media" que aparece en el END del primer bloque sea reconocida en el bloque intermedio del segundo bloque BEGIN END, esta vacia, diria que una vez termina el END la pierde, aunque sorprendentemente la recupera al final, aunque a mi me da una media mala, no parece correcta

Comment: Ahora estaba probando con pipes, y de momento saco la media asi: `awk -F ";" '{x+=$13; next} END{print x/NR}' archivo.csv` y esa si es correcta, pero luego quiero reemplazar ese valor en la columna 13 del csv con valores NULL y aun no se como :-)

Comment: @masterguru y como reescribirías uno nuevo?

Comment: A lo bruto :-)  Agregaba un `printf($1 ";" $2 ";" $3 ";" $4 ";" $5 ";" $6 ";" $7 ";" $8 ";" $9 ";" $10 ";" $11 ";" $12 ";" $13 ";" $14 ";" $15 "\n");` en el primer bucle debajo de `count += 1` y un `printf($1 ";" $2 ";" $3 ";" $4 ";" $5 ";" $6 ";" $7 ";" $8 ";" $9 ";" $10 ";" $11 ";" $12 ";" media ";" $14 ";" $15 "\n");` debajo del '`count2 += 1` pero ese sale vacio, no lee la variable `media`, ni la `$13`, ni nada

Comment: Con esos cambios y con el operador `>` al final de tu comando creas un archivo nuevo, por ejemplo, `gawk -f script.awk archivo.csv > archivo_nuevo.csv`

Comment: Nada, tengo que desistir, no llego a tanto con el awk, pero seguro que hay un modo sencillo de conseguirlo. Suerte!

Comment: Un par de aclaraciones: La media que estas calculando solo cuenta las columnas con valores no NULL por lo que veo, por lo tanto esa formula que te he pasado antes no te valdrá si realmente quieres eso, pues tambien los tiene en cuenta.  En cuanto al primer `printf` tan largo lo puedes reemplazar por `print $0` y te imprimira la linea completa sin cambios, que viene a ser lo mismo pero sin tanto código

Comment: gracias @masterguru Efectivamente la media queria calcularla sin tener en cuenta los valores no null y en el segundo begin ya he periddo ese valor. Seguire peleando o buscando otro modo de hacerlo!

Comment: Acabo de poner una respuesta que por fin pone la media en la columna 13 cuando es NULL en un nuevo archivo. Miratela a ver si te sirve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editado

***Corrección de errores:***

1. Por error tipográfico habia puesto `line[$i]` en lugar de `line[i]` en determinadas partes del codigo
2. He quitado el `sub()` porque cambiaba todos los **NULL** de la linea, no solo la columna 13. Ahora uso `split` para generar una matriz de columnas de cada linea, realizar el cambio en la columna 13 y recomponer la linea modificada que vuelco en la salida al archivo `nuevo_archivo.csv`

---

Creo que lo tengo. Realmente no hacia falta usar dos `BEGIN-END` ni intentar pasar la variable de uno a otro, pues no funcionaba.

Adjunto el código con los comentarios para que sea autoexplicativo:

```
BEGIN {
    # separador del csv
    FS= ";"

    # Iniciamos variables
    total=0;
    count=0;
}
{
    # Excluimos la primera linea de encabezado
    if (NR!=1) {

        # Creamos matriz con contenido completo de cada linea excepto cabecera
        line[NR] = $0;

        # Si la columna 13 no contiene NULL
        if ($13 != "NULL") {

            # Agregamos el contador para el divisor de la media
            count++;

            # Sumamos el valor de la columna 13 al total
            total += $13;
        }

    } else {

        # Creamos el archivo con la cabecera borrando el anterior si existe
        print $0 > "nuevo_archivo.csv";
    }
}
END {
    # Calculamos la media
    media = total/count;

    # Recorremos las lineas completas guardadas excluyendo la primera que no existe
    for (i = 2; i <= FNR; i++) {

        # Contamos (n) y dividimos la linea en una matriz de columnas
        n = split(line[i], array, ";");

        # Si el valor de la columna 13 es NULL le asignamos la media
        if (array[13] == "NULL") {
            array[13] = media;
        }

        # recomponemos la linea
        for (j=1; j in array; j++) {

            # Si aun no es la ultima columna le agregamos ";"
            if (n != j ) {
                salida = salida array[j]";"
            } else {
                # esta es la última columna sin ";"
                salida = salida array[j]
            }
        }

        # agregamos el resultado en el archivo
        print salida >> "nuevo_archivo.csv";

        # limpiamos la variable salida para empezar de nuevo en el siguiente ciclo
        salida = "";
    }
}
```

Ya me dirás si te funciona bien. Haz los apaños que creas convenientes. Basándome en los datos visualizados en tu captura de tu CSV esto deberia funcionarte bien para ellos. Si hay variaciones tu mismo ya tienes un punto de partida para seguir puliendolas.

Comment: No consigo hacer que funcione, pero mil gracias por tus comentarios y respuestas, pues me ayudan a seguir intentándolo sin volverme tan loca!

Comment: Para que funcione ejecutalo asi: `gawk -f script.awk archivo.csv` donde `script.awk` es el código que ves arriba.  A mi me funciona estupendamente.  Cuando termine su ejecución deberias encontrarte con un nuevo archivo llamado `nuevo_archivo.csv` en el mismo directorio donde lo has ejecutado asi

Comment: En todo caso, cuando dices que no funciona... que error te da?  no crea ese nuevo_archivo.csv?  o que ocurre?

Comment: no da error, pero el fichero que me genera está vacío y no logro que pinte nada :( Además, a este punto ahora he llegado sin cabecera, porque filtros previos a este punto no he conseguido mantenerla. Soy un desastre peleando a ciegas con esto! He omitido el if de la cabecera y llego a pintar la media, pero en el for le pierdo la pista a la información.

Comment: @Maggie: Puedes editar la pregunta y pegar unas pocas lineas del CSV en modo texto lugar de la imagen?  Yo me habia creado el mio a pelo y quizas ahi esta el problema, en algo que desconozco de tu CSV.

Comment: @Maggie: Tambien veo que H5 (columna H registro 5) tiene este valor = `*;*;` que seguramente dan problemas tambien por repetir el delimitador, a menos que el CSV esté entrecomillado, con lo cual aun podria tener solucion.  Pero para ello necesitamos ver el CSV en formato texto tal como lo estas trabajando, no en una imagen.

Comment: He añadido la url de descarga, en otro punto lo descargué con curl. "https://datos.madrid.es/egobfiles/MANUAL/300110/AccidentesBicicletas_2021.csv" También hay otras variables con null de manera que el sub no funcionaría exactamente cmo quiero porque solo debo modificar esa columna y sino sustituira en cada linea cuando encuentre el patrón.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132650/discussion-between-maggie-and-masterguru).

Comment: eres una maquina!!! Mil gracias, voy a ver si consigo adaptarlo. Tu codigo funciona genial.