# Como filtrar con awk un csv sin perder la cabecera

Tags: csv, filtro, awk

Tengo un csv separado por ; --> file.csv
Estoy filtrado por una columna que ocupa la posición 8 con valores distintos de "Desconocido".
El problema es que pierdo la cabecera, ¿Cómo puedo incluir que se salte la primera fila?

Estoy ejecutando:

```
awk - F ";" '$8!=Desconocido"' file.csv > file2.csv
```

Comment: ¿Perder o agregar?  Si te miras la solucion que te di aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506044/sustituir-valores-de-un-csv-con-awk veras como me salto la cabecera por si es eso lo que quieres

Comment: Realmente quiero que la salte en el filtro o agregarla después.  El objetivo tener un csv con su cabecera y las lineas filtradas. Gracias por tu apoyo!

Answer (score 2):

Seguramente haya una manera mas elegante, pero finalmente lo he conseguido de este modo:

```
awk -F ";" '{if ($8!=Desconocido" || NR==1) print $1,";",$2,";",...,$8}' file.csv > file2.csv
```

En los `...` he indicado todas las columnas que debía pasar de un fichero a otro.

Comment: Márcate la solución como aceptada si ya lo das por bueno (creo que después de 12 horas puedes hacerlo cuando es tu propia respuesta) y asi evitamos dejar preguntas en el aire para siempre.

Comment: Es correcto. También puedes decir `'$8 != "Desconocido" || NR==1'` directamente, si quieres imprimir toda la línea (pues `{print $0}`, es decir imprimir toda la línea, es la acción por defecto de Awk cuando se encuentra con una condición cierta)

Comment: masterguru aun no me deja aceptarla, pero lo haré en cuanto pueda. ferdoqui sin duda mucho mas limpio como dices! Asi ahorro tener que escribir todas las columnas. Muchísimas gracias a ambos!